# Cypress blocks cookies sent from third party response when the same site attribute is not set. How to store such blocked cookie values and use them

Tags: https, single-sign-on, cypress, setcookie, samesite

We are trying to test a third party sign in (Single Sign On) flow using Cypress.
Cypress blocks cookies sent in third party response when the SameSite attribute is not set when tested with Electron V-94.
How to store such blocked cookie values and use them?
The same works when tested from normal browser with third party cookie even with no SameSite attribute set.
Is there a way to prevent cypress from blocking it or can the cookies received from third party can be stored and used? If so, how?

Answer (score 4):

I've just been fighting the same issue, I resolved it by intercepting all requests, checking if they had a set-cookie header(s) and rewriting the SameSite attribute. There's probably a neater way to do it, as this does clutter up the cypress dashboard a little. You can add this as a command for easy reuse:

In your commands file:

```ts
declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable<Subject> {
    disableSameSiteCookieRestrictions(): void;
  }
}

Cypress.Commands.add('disableSameSiteCookieRestrictions', () => {
  cy.intercept('*', (req) => {
    req.on('response', (res) => {
      if (!res.headers['set-cookie']) {
        return;
      }

      const disableSameSite = (headerContent: string): string => {
        return headerContent.replace(/samesite=(lax|strict)/ig, 'samesite=none');
      }

      if (Array.isArray(res.headers['set-cookie'])) {
        res.headers['set-cookie'] = res.headers['set-cookie'].map(disableSameSite);
      } else {
        res.headers['set-cookie'] = disableSameSite(res.headers['set-cookie']);
      }
    })
  });
});
```

Usage:

```ts
  it('should login using third party idp', () => {
    cy.disableSameSiteCookieRestrictions();
    //add test body here
  });
```

or alteratively, run it before each test:

```ts
  beforeEach(() => cy.disableSameSiteCookieRestrictions());
```